# FB Messenger Security

Tags: security, facebook-messenger

Does anyone know how secure Facebook Messenger communication is? If you are having 1x1 chat (writing messages) or making a voice call, is it encrypted (end to end)?

I know if you are using facebook.com for chat, it is on HTTPS and that is secure.  My question is related to the Messenger app on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is secure.  The connection is made using TLS 1.2.  This is from a tcpdump capture on my device:

```
192.168.0.11  31.13.69.195 (edge-mqtt-shv-01-iad3.facebook.com)  TLSv1.2  Application Data
31.13.69.195  192.168.0.11                                       TLSv1.2  Application Data
```

Comment: Good information! What'd be your answer I asked the same question for Snapchat?

Comment: @SarpSTA I don't have Snapchat, I'd suggest posting a separate question.